# Exporting arrow function in react for unit testing in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

The error I keep getting is that checkIfBlank is undefined I understand that I have to export the function however I don't know how to for an Arrow Function

Here is my function in register.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import bycrypt from 'bcryptjs';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

import { useState } from "react";
// const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

import InputBoxForInfo from "../components/input-box-for-info";
import Button from "../components/button";
import "./register.css";


const Register = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const salt = bycrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  const hashedPassword = bycrypt.hashSync(password,salt);
  const[exist, setExistence] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const postDetails = () =>{
    axios.post("http://localhost:3002/api/post/register",{name:name, surname:surname, email: email, username: username, password: hashedPassword});
    setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
    }, 1000);
    
  }

  const checkIfUserExists = () =>{
    axios
    .get("http://localhost:3002/api/get/doesExist/" + username)
    .then(function(response){
      const userExists = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
      if (JSON.stringify(userExists) == "[]"){
        setErrorMessage('Account created successfully');
        postDetails();
      }
      else{
        setErrorMessage('Username already exists');
      }
    });
  }

  
   const checkIfBlank=()=>{
    const emailPattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    const passwordPattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/;

    //If fields empty, warn
    if(name == "" || surname =="" || email == "" || username == "" || password==""){
      alert("Please enter all details");
    }

    //not empty
    else{
      //check if email correct and password is strong
      if(emailPattern.test(email) && passwordPattern.test(password)){
        checkIfUserExists();
      }
      //otherwise warn
      else{
        //email not corect format
        if(!emailPattern.test(email)){
          setErrorMessage('Please enter a valid email');
        }
        if(!passwordPattern.test(password)){
          setErrorMessage("Please enter a stronger password");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const handleRegister = () => {
    // Do something with the input values
    console.log(
      `Name: ${name}, Surname: ${surname} Email: ${email}, Username: ${username}, Password: ${hashedPassword}`
    );
    checkIfBlank();
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="register-container">
      <Helmet>
        <title>register - Project ARENA</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="register - Project ARENA" />
      </Helmet>
      <div className="register-container1">
        <Link to="/" className="register-navlink">
          <svg
            viewBox="0 0 877.7142857142857 1024"
            className="register-backbtn"
          >
            <path d="M519.429 797.143l58.286-58.286c14.286-14.286 14.286-37.143 0-51.429l-175.429-175.429 175.429-175.429c14.286-14.286 14.286-37.143 0-51.429l-58.286-58.286c-14.286-14.286-37.143-14.286-51.429 0l-259.429 259.429c-14.286 14.286-14.286 37.143 0 51.429l259.429 259.429c14.286 14.286 37.143 14.286 51.429 0zM877.714 512c0 242.286-196.571 438.857-438.857 438.857s-438.857-196.571-438.857-438.857 196.571-438.857 438.857-438.857 438.857 196.571 438.857 438.857z"></path>
          </svg>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="register-container5">
        <span className="register-text">
          <span>Register</span>
          <br></br>
        </span>

        <InputBoxForInfo
          buttonText="NAME"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          rootClassName="input-box-for-info-root-class-name"
        ></InputBoxForInfo>

        <InputBoxForInfo
          buttonText="SURNAME"
          onChange={(e) => setSurname(e.target.value)}
          rootClassName="input-box-for-info-root-class-name2"
        ></InputBoxForInfo>
    
        <InputBoxForInfo
          buttonText="EMAIL"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          rootClassName="input-box-for-info-root-class-name3"
        ></InputBoxForInfo>
    
        <InputBoxForInfo
          buttonText="USERNAME"
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          rootClassName="input-box-for-info-root-class-name4"
        ></InputBoxForInfo>
    
        <InputBoxForInfo
          buttonText="PASSWORD"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          isPassword
          rootClassName="input-box-for-info-root-class-name5"
        ></InputBoxForInfo>
    
        <br></br>
        <Button 
          name="Register"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("Register button clicked");
            handleRegister();
          }}
          rootClassName="button-root-class-name"
        ></Button>
        
        <br></br>
        {errorMessage && <div className="error">{errorMessage}</div>}
        <span className="register-text3">Already have an account?</span>
        <Link to="/login" className="register-navlink1 button">
          Login here
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Here is my unit test for the above code

```
import React  from 'react';
import Register from './register';

// Import the necessary modules
const axios = require('axios');

// Import the function to be tested
import { checkIfBlank } from './register.js';
//const { checkIfBlank } = require('./register');

// Test suite for checkIfBlank function
describe('checkIfBlank', () => {

  // Mock the setErrorMessage and postDetails functions
  let setErrorMessage = jest.fn();
  let postDetails = jest.fn();

  // Test case when all fields are filled in and valid
  test('valid input', () => {
    // Set up the input data
    const name = 'John';
    const surname = 'Doe';
    const email = 'john.doe@example.com';
    const username = 'johndoe';
    const password = 'Passw0rd';

    // Call the function
    checkIfBlank(name, surname, email, username, password, setErrorMessage, postDetails);

    // Check that setErrorMessage and postDetails were not called
    expect(setErrorMessage).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(postDetails).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // Test case when one or more fields are empty
  test('missing field', () => {
    // Set up the input data
    const name = '';
    const surname = 'Doe';
    const email = 'john.doe@example.com';
    const username = 'johndoe';
    const password = 'Passw0rd';

    // Call the function
    checkIfBlank(name, surname, email, username, password, setErrorMessage, postDetails);

    // Check that setErrorMessage was called with the correct message
    expect(setErrorMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Please enter all details');

    // Check that postDetails was not called
    expect(postDetails).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // Test case when the email is invalid
  test('invalid email', () => {
    // Set up the input data
    const name = 'John';
    const surname = 'Doe';
    const email = 'johndoe@examplecom';
    const username = 'johndoe';
    const password = 'Passw0rd';

    // Call the function
    checkIfBlank(name, surname, email, username, password, setErrorMessage, postDetails);

    // Check that setErrorMessage was called with the correct message
    expect(setErrorMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Please enter a valid email');

    // Check that postDetails was not called
    expect(postDetails).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // Test case when the password is weak
  test('weak password', () => {
    // Set up the input data
    const name = 'John';
    const surname = 'Doe';
    const email = 'john.doe@example.com';
    const username = 'johndoe';
    const password = 'password';

    // Call the function
    checkIfBlank(name, surname, email, username, password, setErrorMessage, postDetails);

    // Check that setErrorMessage was called with the correct message
    expect(setErrorMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Please enter a stronger password');

    // Check that postDetails was not called
    expect(postDetails).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I have tried the following:

This in the resgiter.js in the fucntion
`export const checkIfBlank=()=>{`

At the end of register.js and add the beginning of regsiter.js
`export {checkIfBlank};`

At the end of register.js and add the beginning of regsiter.js
`module.exports = { checkIfBlank };`

This in the resgiter.js in the fucntion
`module.exports = checkIfBlank=()=>{`

Comment: you have two imports from `./register` and one looks like a default import. Are you explicitly saying `Register` is a default export in `register.js`? If so you can remove the default keyword and just use `import { Register, checkIfBlank } from './register'`

Comment: @about14sheep
I have seemed to identify my issue as the checkIfBlank is inside the Register function
is there a way around that?

Comment: you can movie it outside of the `Register` function and do as i mentioned above. or you might be able to do `Register.checkIfBlank` but i would need to see the entire `Register` implementation to know for sure

Comment: @about14sheep I have edited the post to show the whole register.js
I tried to take it out of the register function however I encounter more errors. Thank you

Comment: I have added an answer according to the new information provided. If this solves your problem please mark it as the accepted answer so we can close out the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to import two different methods, however you have declared the `Register` function as the default export: `export default Register`.

If you are wanting to export both the `Register` function and the `checkIfBlank` function you need to change your export to a list:

```js
export {
  Register,
  checkIfBlank
}
```

Now, when you go to import the methods you need to do this:

```js
import { Register, checkIfBlank } from './register';
```

You can read more about the `export` keyword in the [mdn docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: I have tried this before you mentioned it 
I get this error: `register.js: Export 'checkIfBlank' is not defined. (165:2)`

Comment: did you move `checkIfBlank` outside of the `Register` function?

Comment: I am going to now, my team member was supposed to code the functions outside but they did not. They are currently fixing it